# ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 System.Management.Automation issue with DNX

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.NET and working on a personal project to learn ASP.NET in-depth.

So to get started, I created a new ASP Web project and selected ASP 5 Empty MVC template. Then I installed System.Management.Automation package from Nuget and then created some cs files in Models folder called `PowerShellCmd.cs` and `PowerShellModule.cs`.

`PowerShellCmd.cs` just contains get and set properties. Please see the below code:

```
namespace Automation.Models
{
    public class PowerShellCmd
    {
        public string CmdLets { get; set; }
        public string CmdOutput { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`PowerShellModule.cs` does the automation task and I loaded `System.Management.Automation` at the top so I can use them in the code. Below is my code:

```
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace Automation.Models
{
    public class PowerShellModule
    {
        public void ExecuteCode()
        {
            PowerShellCmd command = new PowerShellCmd();
            var shell = PowerShell.Create();

            shell.Commands.AddScript(command.CmdLets);

            var results = shell.Invoke();
        }

    }
}
```

When I hover over System.Management.Automation, I get reference is available  for DNX 4.5.1 and not available for DNX 5.0. Please see the below screenshot.

[image]

And when I build the code, I get below error:

[image]

By default it is using DNX 5.0 to find System.Management.Automation. How do I change that to use DNX4.5.1?

Comment: It looks like you are missing a reference. Try adding a reference to System.Management to the project and compile again.

Comment: @lumee - the reference does exist under Reference -> DNX4.5.1 -> System.Management.Automation. There are no DNX5.0 dependency available in Nuget repo to use. Only available for DNX4.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package System.Management.Automation is not supported in .NET Core 5 framework (DNX Core). .NET Core 5 is a subset of the .NET Framework. You can read more about it here.

http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/dotnetcore.html

if you only want to use full .Net framework (DNX 4.5.1), you can go to the project.json file and remove the Core framework. After that, your project.json file's frameworks will look as below.

```
 "frameworks": {
        "dnx451": { }
    },
```